# WiX: pulling in a CustomTable from a Fragment WITHOUT a CustomAction

Tags: wix, fragment

I have a custom table defined in a `<Fragment>` that I want to link into the main **.wxs** file. My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344608/reference-custom-table-in-wix-fragment-file), but my fragment does not have a `<CustomAction>` tag to refer to, and there is no `<CustomTableRef>` tag to use in the main file.

Is the only way to pull in a `<Fragment>` that does not have a `<...Ref>`able tag to inject a dummy tag that *can* be `Ref`'d? -- e.g. a `<Component>` with a "never-install" condition, or a `<CustomAction>` that never gets scheduled to run (or does something totally benign like setting property `Foo` to `""`)?

I am looking for a recommended best practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your fragment you can create a property like so:

```
<Property Id="IncludeMyFragment" Value="1" />
```

Then reference that fragment in your source like so:

```
<PropertyRef Id="IncludeMyFragment"/>
```

That should pull in the contents of the fragment.

Comment: That would also have the side effect of a property set in the  built MSI that doesn't do anything.  Not the end of the world, but not clean either. You can avoid this by ommitting the Value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

When using references, the entire fragment is consumed.   Are you defining a custom table simply to be documentation / metadata regarding the MSI or are you actually using it in a data driven custom action?  Typically I would define the custom action and custom table schema in a single fragment so that when someone references the custom action they get the supporting infrastructure.  Other fragments can then contain the actual data for said custom table ( implementation specific ).